# & symbol in php equivalent in Java

Tags: java, php, symbols

Can the following

```
<?=($Num&1) ? "odd" : "even"?>
```

translate to an equivalent in Java?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`String s = (num % 2 == 0) ? "even" : "odd";`

To be thorough, that isn't the same operator that you're using (bitwise AND). Bitwise AND is the same in java, so you could also write your php line like:

`String s = (num & 1 == 0) ? "even" : "odd";`

Answer (score 2):

A direct translation would be:

```
string s = ( num & 1 != 0 ) ? "odd" : "even"
```

* note: not entirely sure if the `!=0` part is strictly necessary.